# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at mapping.php:74:17)

Tags: php, jquery

i know that this eror has been asked a lot in this site, and i've been lookin for the answer but still doesn't get it
so please help me with this code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var count = 0;
      $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
        count++;
        var html = '';
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td><select name="item_name[]" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" ><option value="">Select Name</option><?php echo fill_select_boxing($connect, "10"); ?></select></td>';
        html += '<td><select id="item_cat" name="item_category[]" class="form-control item_category" data-sub_category_id="'+count+'"><option value="">Select Dist</option><?php echo fill_select_boxting($connect, "1"); ?></select></td>'; 
        html += '<td><select name="item_sub_category[]" class="form-control item_sub_category" id="item_sub_category'+count+'"><option value="">Select Category</option><?php echo fill_select_boxting($connect, "2"); ?></select></td>';
        html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td>';
        $('tbody').append(html);
        
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
        
      });
      
      $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      });
    
    });
</script>
```

and i got this eror in console

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

at this code

```
html += '<td><select name="item_name[]" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" ><option value="">Select Name</option><?php echo fill_select_boxing($connect, "10"); ?></select></td>';
```

here the fill fuction that i use

```
<?php
include('database_connection.php');

function fill_select_boxing($connect, $cust_id)
{
 $query = "
  SELECT * FROM tbl_customer 
  WHERE parent_cust_id = '".$cust_id."'
 ";

 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

 $statement->execute();

 $result = $statement->fetchAll();

 $output = '';

 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output .= '<option value="'.$row["cust_id"].'">'.$row["cust_name"].'</option>';
 }

 return $output;
}
?>
```

the thing is, its work well in development, but i got the eror in production, So I'm not sure whats wrong with it

Comment: At a guess, one of the option values rendered by PHP contains a single quote mark, which is throwing off your string. Try using template literals instead of simple concatenation.

Comment: can you give an example of this template literals ?

Comment: Just standard string concatenation in JS. As in `html +=...`. Use of [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) is likely to give you less trouble as it won't care about things like quote marks in your database data. Templating is generally a better design overall for creating HTML content on-the-fly in JS anyway.

Comment: well i will try lookin for templating in the future, but guess what, your guess about the option values is right, but not because of a quote mark, but there's enter/return key in the values, i delete it in the DB and it's work like a charm, anyway thanks for the insight

Comment: Try checking whether the PHP result that is returned looks like the result you would expect

Comment: Also, be warned that your `SELECT` query is highly vulnerable for SQL injections. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: yeah you're right, for now i can relax about it cause it was just for my school project but im still have a lot to learn including how to prevent sql injection, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

solved, like the commenter say, there's something that trowing off my string and its the option values itself that maybe has quote mark or (enter/return key in my case) since my option values come from the database, i just search for the value that supposed to have quote mark or return key, and change it